# How to Translate the solution of a SAT solver (assuming a "SAT" result) back into the problem domain?

Tags: z3, solver, sat

Say, I have a SAT result for a problem in Cryptominisat or z3. How can I translate it back into the problem domain?

Answer (score 1):

This can be explained by using a small example.

A [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) like [CryptoMiniSat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat) requires [CNF clauses](https://jix.github.io/varisat/manual/0.2.0/formats/dimacs.html) as input.
To create such clauses, a tool like [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) can be used.

Input to [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/):

```
BC1.0
f := A & ~B | ~A & B;
ASSIGN f;
```

Output generated by [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/):

```
c This is a CNF SAT formula in the DIMACS CNF format,
c produced with the bc2cnf translator by Tommi Junttila;
c see http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/index.html
c Modified and compiled by Axel Kemper: Jun 18 2017
c
c Commandline:
c .\bc2cnf -v test6.bc.txt test6.dimacs.txt
c CNF file created: Sat Dec 12 18:56:36 2020
c
c f <-> 1
c B <-> 4
c A <-> 5
p cnf 5 10
1 -2 0
1 -3 0
-1 3 2 0
1 0
-2 -5 0
-2 4 0
2 -4 5 0
-3 -4 0
-3 5 0
3 -5 4 0
```

[CryptoMiniSat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat) Solution:
(command: `cryptominisat --verb 2 --dumpresult=test6.cms.txt test6.dimacs.txt`)

```
SAT
1 2 -3 4 -5 0
```

The first line of the solution "SAT" indicates, that a solution was found.
The second line lists the input values which result in a true-valued output.
In this case: `Variable 4 [A]=true, Variable 5 [B]=false`
Variable `1` stands for the output variable `f`. Variables `2` and `3` are auxiliary variables.

[Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) can be used as [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT). But it also contains other solvers and is named *theorem prover* by *Microsoft*.